# How to make a "find and update" query in Paris

Tags: php, orm, idiorm

I am using [Paris with Idiorm](http://j4mie.github.com/idiormandparis/) and I am having problems finding in the documentation a clear instruction on how to find and update a table.

I don't want to insert a sql query into the script. Is there any other way?

Paris is an Active Record implementation based on Idiorm.
Idiorm is an object-relational mapper and fluent query builder.

I am interested in doing something like count = count + 1 all in one go

Comment: Can you explain what `Paris` is?  The SO tag is empty, and I cannot find a [reasonable entry on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_%28disambiguation%29).

Comment: I didn't say more because I expected answers from someone already using it, but @Charles edited my question.Thanks!

Comment: to update a record **is** in the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this on their [github site](https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm):

Updating records
To update the database, change one or more of the properties of the object, then call the save method to commit the changes to the database. Again, you can change the values of the object's properties either by using the set method or by setting the value of the property directly:

```
$person = ORM::for_table('person')->find_one(5);

// The following two forms are equivalent
$person->set('name', 'Bob Smith');
$person->age = 20;

// Syncronise the object with the database
$person->save();
Creating new records
```

To add a new record, you need to first create an "empty" object instance. You then set values on the object as normal, and save it.

```
$person = ORM::for_table('person')->create();

$person->name = 'Joe Bloggs';
$person->age = 40;

$person->save();
```

After the object has been saved, you can call its id() method to find the autogenerated primary key value that the database assigned to it.

Checking whether a property has been modified
To check whether a property has been changed since the object was created (or last saved), call the is_dirty method:

```
$name_has_changed = $person->is_dirty('name'); // Returns true or false
```

Comment: and how can i do something like count = count + 1 ?

Comment: @andrei I suppose you could to `$person->number = $person->number + 1;` then.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation on the github page, in idiorm you can update a record by doing the following:

```
$person = ORM::for_table('person')->find_one(5);

// The following two forms are equivalent
$person->set('name', 'Bob Smith');
$person->age = 20;

// Syncronise the object with the database
$person->save();
```

Or to do it in 'paris' you do:

```
$user = Model::factory('User')->find_one($id);
$user->name = 'Paris';
$user->save();
```

Comment: and how can i do something like count = count + 1 ?

Comment: I mean an incrementation query something like UPDATE record SET row = row + 1 WHERE condition